# Powershell - how do I do this

Tags: powershell

```
Get-content -path z:\path\name.txt |
foreach {
        (get-hotfix -Computername $_ |
          Sort-object IUnstalledon)[-1]
}
```

---

I would like to count and place the count in front of the (get-hotfix in the output)

```
1 computer-name update ncncncncn cncncncncncn date time
2 computer name.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
#Count variable
$i = 0
Get-content -path z:\path\name.txt |
foreach {
        $hotfix = (get-hotfix -Computername $_ | Sort-object IUnstalledon)[-1]

        #Create your output string "Count ComputerName Hotfix"
        Write-Output "$i $_ $hotfix"
        $i++
}
```